# Mysql - Inner Join problem, output appears more times than needed

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem. I'm trying to get all authors which have exactly one post. It works quite good, but, it shows me the same output exactly 3 times more.
[image]

[image]

Query:

```
select a.name as 'Name', a.surname as 'Surname' from author as a inner join post as p on (select count(body) from post where authorID = a.ID) = 1;
```

[image]

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data or queries. Include data as text in your question, please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `inner join post as p` but `on` clause is not related to `p` at all, looks like an `EXISTS` subquery or using `GROUP BY ... HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` could be better choices.

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use single quotes for identifiers such as column aliases. Yes, sadly MySQL accepts that, but in SQL single quotes are usually for string (or date...) literals. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an error. Use backticks for identifiers that have special characters in them or are case sensitive or preferably don't use special characters and case sensitive identifiers at all. Identifiers don't need to be "pretty", "pretty" headers and such are a job for the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a result for each `post`, instead of for each author. This is because you join the inner query that fetches from `post`.

I'd use the inbuilt aggregate tokens to get the desired output:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, a.name AS 'Name', a.surname AS 'Surname'
FROM author a
JOIN post p
ON p.authorID = a.ID
GROUP BY p.authorID
HAVING COUNT(p.body) = 1;
```